# Is there a way to stop gaining experience in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've reached a certain level. I want to be able to queue lower level dungeons in the dungeon/party finder without becoming too high for them. Is there a way to stop leveling or do I simply have no option but to keep leveling?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [WoW Wiki: Level Locking](http://www.wowwiki.com/Level_locking)

> To keep your character from leveling higher for any reason, follow these steps:
>
> For the Horde faction:
>
> 1. Go to the Hall of the Brave, Valley of Honor in Orgrimmar.
> 2. Look for and talk to Horde Slahtz.
> 3. For 10g he will put a hold on all experience points earned.
>
> You can enable your experience again by seeing Slahtz and paying another 10g.
>
> For the Alliance faction:
>
> 1. Go to the War Room, Stormwind Keep in Stormwind City.
> 2. Look for and talk to Alliance Behsten.
> 3. For 10g he will put a hold on all experience points earned.
>
> You can enable your experience again by seeing Behsten and paying another 10g .

Comment: Interesting tidbit: "Behsten Slahtz" is a play at the "Best-In-Slot" terminology that frequently accompanies twinking, which is typically what this service is used for :)

Comment: This cannot be done on trial accounts.

Comment: Not that you need it for dungeons, since you'll still have access for all the earliest dungeons by the topmost 20th level of trial.

Comment: As a side note: Disabling your XP will give a debuff to others in your party, also affecting their XP gain. (to basically disabled).

Comment: Slahtz moved.  He's now on the third floor of the Orgrimmar barracks.

Answer (score 5):

You can talk to [Slahtz](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=35364) (Horde) or [Behsten](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=35365) (Alliance)

They will charge 10g each time you decide to switch to gaining/not gaining experience

Answer (score 5):

You can lock your level by going to the an Experience Eliminator NPC([Alliance](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=35365)/[Horde](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=35364)) and paying for it:

> If you do not want to gain XP (ex. for the purpose of making a Twink),
>   you can visit  Behsten or  Slahtz to turn off all experience gains. It
>   costs 10g to disable and another 10g to enable it.

[source](http://www.wowwiki.com/Experience_point#Level_Locking)

Answer (score -4):

You cannot lock your experience in World of Warcraft, the ability to do so was disabled in an update.

Comment: -1 Source? I don't play WoW, but a cursory google search implied that level locking is still around.

Comment: Totally wrong. You obviously don't play WoW. Please do not post your imaginations as an answer. Both NPCs are still there and both still provide the service.

Comment: The ability to lock your level was not disabled in an update, you can still lock and unlock your experience gains as normal. See the accepted answer for the NPC you need to speak to in order to achieve this.